# Achieve conditional function call by template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection

I'm trying to do dependency injection to the legacy code, since performance matters, dynamic polymorphism cannot be applied.
The following is my current thought, it CANNOT be compiled.

```
// myclass.h     
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(GlobalsImpl *globals) { globalsImpl = globals; }
        MyClass(GlobalsTest *globals) { globalsTest = globals; }
        std::string test();
    
    private:
        template<bool> auto getGlobals();
    
    private:
    bool isImpl;
    GlobalsImpl *globalsImpl;
    GlobalsTest *globalsTest;
    };

// myclass.cc
    template<bool> auto MyClass::getGlobals() { return getGlobals<> }
    template<> Impl * MyClass::getGlobals<true>() { return globalsImpl; }
    template<> Test * MyClass::getGlobals<false>() { return globalsTest; }
    
    std::string MyClass::test() { return ""; }
```

My intuition is to achieve if test called, then return globalsTest; else return globalsImpl.
globalsImpl is the real implementation, while globalsTest is my injection.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Whether it is supposed to return the test pointer or not isn't known until runtime anyway. Wouldn't it be semantically incorrect to e.g., set the `globalsTest` member, and then ask for the `globalsImpl` member?

Comment: You can't do compile-time polymorphism at runtime. That's a contradiction. You need conditional compilation instead, which could be as simple as an `#ifdef` / `#else` where one has `using GlobalsType = GlobalsImpl;` and the other has `using GlobalsType = GlobalsTest;` and then you use `GlobalsType` everywhere in your code that you need to dynamically decide which to use.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's the point. I want to call funcForTest() if in test, else call funcForTest(). Any suggestion for my requirement?

Comment: I've tried your suggesion. But it would change hundreds lines of code... It's in a big file of 1k  lines of cc file.

Comment: Another option is that every single type or function that needs to use `GlobalsXXX` is a template, but this won't work in cases where you reference the type in the signature of a virtual function (you can't have a template virtual function -- though you can have a non-template virtual function as a member of a template type).

Comment: This is the choice I've considered. But still needs to involve like 40 files.